# Cannot get second while to loop properly

Tags: c++

I'm making a function that removes elements from a string. However, I cant seem to get both of my loops to work together. The first while loop works flawlessly. I looked into it and I believe it might be because when "find_last_of" isn't found, it still returns a value (which is throwing off my loop). I haven't been able to figure out how I can fix it. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

   string foo(string word) {
      string compare = "!@#$";
      string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    while(word.find_first_of(compare) < word.find_first_of(alphabet)) {
        int position = word.find_first_of(compare);
        word = word.substr(++position);
    }
           while(word.find_last_of(compare) > word.find_last_of(alphabet)){
              int size = word.length();
              word = word.substr(0, --size);
         }  
    return word;
}

int main() {
    cout << foo("!!hi!!");

    return 0;
}
```

I wrote it like this so compound words would not be affected. Desired result: "hi"

Comment: The value that `find_last_of` returns if it could not find a match is called `npos` and is unsigned with value of `-1` (which converts to whatever maximum value of `size_type` is. Either check for it specifically and then do the comparison, or do refactor a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but how about replacing the second loop with this:

```
string::size_type p = word.find_last_not_of(compare);
if(p != string::npos)
  word = word.substr(0, ++p);
```

Comment: Sorry, the result I'm looking for is "hi" (without any extra characters).

Comment: @user2780598: this will do it.

Comment: That it will, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you just want to trim certain characters from the front and back of `word` or if you want to remove every one of a certain set of characters from `word` no matter where they are.  Based on the first sentence of your question, I'll assume you want to do the latter: remove all characters in `compare` from `word`.

A better strategy would be to more directly examine each character to see if it needs to be removed, and if so, do so, all in one pass through `word`.  Since `compare` is quite short, something like this is probably good enough:

```
// Rewrite word by removing all characters in compare (and then erasing the
// leftover space, if any, at the end).  See std::remove_if() docs.
word.erase(std::remove_if(word.begin(), 
                          word.end(),
                          // Returns true if a character is to be removed.
                          [&](const char ch) {
                            return compare.find(ch) != compare.npos;
                          }),
           word.end());
```

BTW, I'm not sure why there is both a `compare` and `alphabet` string in your example.  It seems you would only need to define one or the other, and not both.  A character is either one to keep or one to remove.